# Swift generic Type inheriting from another generic type

Tags: swift, generics

I am trying to get the code below working in a playground:

```
public protocol SomeTypeProtocol {
    associatedtype T
    func convertTo<TNew:SomeTypeProtocol>()-> TNew
}

public class SomeClass<T>: SomeTypeProtocol{

    var item:T
    public init(item:T)
    {
        self.item = item
    }
    public func convertTo<TNew:SomeTypeProtocol where TNew.T : T>()-> TNew
    {
        return SomeClass<TNew.T>(item: item  as! TNew.T)
    }
}
```

Basically, I have a protocol with an associated type T, and a class conforming to that protocol with generic type T, and I need to implement the convertTo function that simply converts the class's type T to another type TNew.T which should be a subclass from T. 
I have this implemented in  other languages like C# and Java, so I am not sure why I can't get it working in Swift.
I am getting the following errors:

```
1) error: type 'TNew.T' constrained to non-protocol type 'T'
    public func convertTo<TNew:SomeTypeProtocol where TNew.T : T>()-> TNew
2) error: cannot invoke initializer for type 'SomeClass<TNew.T>' with an argument list of type '(item: TNew.T)'
        return SomeClass<TNew.T>(item: item as! TNew.T)

3) note: expected an argument list of type '(item: T)'
        return SomeClass<TNew.T>(item: item as! TNew.T)

4)note: protocol requires nested type 'T'
    associatedtype T
```

Comment: I'm not good enough with generics yet to be able to answer your question, but I'd like to point out that the swift convention on building converters is to make extensions that define a new `init` method that takes the desired input to be converted

Comment: You say the static type of `TNew.T` should be a subclass of `T`... are the dynamic types the same though? (Or is the dynamic type of `TNew.T` a superclass of `T`?) Otherwise you can't possibly do this conversion.

Answer (score 0):

> `TNew.T : T`

This is where the problem lies.

The colon, `:`, is used to declare a conformance constraint, not equality. You need to rewrite this as `TNew.T == T` if you want to equate the two types `TNew.T` and `T`.

Comment: Does the equality indicate inheritance as well? I want TNew.T to be a subclass of T not equal to T. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I believe the closest you can get to doing something like that is this:

```
public func convertTo<TNew where TNew : T>()-> SomeClass<TNew>
{
    return SomeClass<TNew>(item: item  as! TNew)
}
```

But I don't believe you can't enforce it being only a subclass and not the same class.

Be careful doing this type of thing with generics. If you're needing to constantly change the Type of your generic, you might want to consider using a different design.